# KBPTriplesAnnotation returns nothing

Tags: stanford-nlp

I tried to test how works the KBPTriplesAnnotation but result output is always empty. What I missed?
Code example:

```
Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,depparse,natlog,parse,mention,coref,kbp,openie,relation");
    props.setProperty("regexner.mapping", "ignorecase=true,validpospattern=^(NN|JJ).*,edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab;edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_cased.tab");

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    IOUtils.console("sentence> ", line -> {
        Annotation ann = new Annotation(line);
        pipeline.annotate(ann);
        for (CoreMap sentence : ann.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.KBPTriplesAnnotation.class).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This may be the Tokensregexner annotator being missing / broken. Which version of the code are you using? Also, is there output for a sentence like "Obama is married to Michelle", which doesn't require the special NER classes?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Make sure you are using the latest jars for everything.

Comment: @GaborAngeli yes indeed was something wrong with tokensrexner. I rebuild and retest the code and now works as expected.